# JQuery Condition [change data only when it's different]

Tags: jquery

I have this Jquery code and i want to refresh content only when it's different with the new data
The html code for the `$title.html` is `"div#title>h4"`

```
function onair() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'player.php', // my json content file
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var artiste = data[0];
            var titre = data[1];
            var title = data[2];
            var cover = data[3];
            var $cover = $("#cover"),
                $title = $("#title");

            if ( $title.html != title ) {
                $cover.fadeOut(300, function (data) {
                    $cover.html("<img src='" + cover + "' width='220px' height='210px'>");
                    $cover.fadeIn(300);
                });
                $title.fadeOut(300, function (data) {
                    $title.html("<h4> " + title + " </h4>");
                    $title.fadeIn(300);
                });
            }

            setTimeout("onair()", 1000);

        }
```

Thank you for help :)

Comment: setTimeout("onair()", 1000); should be setTimeout(onair(), 1000);

Comment: It's the same thing ...

Comment: No it's not, but ignore him as that's wrong.  The 2nd one should not have parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this two changes:

1.

```
// note that `text` must be invoke
if ( $title.text().trim() != title  )
```

2.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    onair();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Should be `text()` not `html()`

Comment: @Archer Is it make any difference when the data within it doesn't contain any HTML tag?

Comment: No, but he wraps it with `H4` tags when he makes changes ;)

Comment: The Json is file like this :
["Artist","Titre","Title","cover"]

Comment: @OussamaTn You must give me the result, then I can find out what happened. What you get when you write `alert(data);` in your `success` function?

Comment: ["Eric Carter - Laurent Wolf", "Explosion", "Eric Carter - Laurent Wolf - Explosion", "/nocover.gif"]

Comment: @OussamaTn You must `.trim()` your title. Also you are shadowing your `title` variable. I've made it correct, look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/VA2A8/4/).

Comment: Thank you @NOX but why i must use `.trim()`

Comment: @OussamaTn Because we were comparing strings like this: `" A"` and `"A"`.

Answer (score 0):

you should add a "last-time" extra parameter in your ajax request. On the songs(server side) must have a "last modified time", and you compare the dates, if the song date is higher than the request date, send it.

Don't forget to post in your ajax response, a "last-time" parameter, to store in your client side and send it in your next request.